# Aspose PDF - get text from page that has a matching string

Tags: c#, text-extraction, aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm working with an existing library - the goal of the library is to pull text out of PDFs to verify against expected values to quality check recorded data vs data in pdf.

I'm looking for a way to succinctly pull a specific page worth of text given a string that should only fall on that specific page.

```
var pdfDocument = new Document(file.PdfFilePath);

var textAbsorber = new TextAbsorber{
    ExtractionOptions = {
        FormattingMode = TextExtractionOptions.TextFormattingMode.Pure
    }
};

pdfDocument.Pages.Accept(textAbsorber);
foreach (var page in pdfDocument.Pages)
{

}
```

I'm stuck inside the `foreach(var page in pdfDocument.Pages)` portion... or is that the right area to be looking?

Comment: In order to extract text from a specific page, you main call Accept() method of specific page by passing TextAbsorber in it i.e pdfDocument.Pages[1].Accept(textAbsorber); Furthermore, in case you still face any issue, please share your sample PDF file with us. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. Please make sure that your test the functionality using latest version of the API. I am Asad Ali and I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Ahh hell... I think I got it... I had the absorber for "All" pages and need to accept the absorber for the single page... I think... I'll post an update to the question as I think I'm closer once i test a moment or two longer.

Comment: @AsadAli added an answer with my quick notes. Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Text Absorber recreated each page - inside the foreach loop.

If the absorber isn't recreated, it keeps text from previous loops.

```
public List<string> ProcessPage(MyInfoClass file, string find)
{
    var pdfDocument = new Document(file.PdfFilePath);

    foreach (Page page in pdfDocument.Pages)
    {
        var textAbsorber = new TextAbsorber {
            ExtractionOptions = {
                FormattingMode = TextExtractionOptions.TextFormattingMode.Pure
            }
        };

        page.Accept(textAbsorber);
        var ext = textAbsorber.Text;
        var exts = ext.Replace("\n", "").Split('\r').ToList();
        if (ext.Contains(find))
            return exts;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your understandings are correct about TextAbsorber keeps all text from each visit unless you re-initialize it. Nevertheless, it is good to know that your issue has been resolved. Please feel free to let us know in case of any further assistance. You may also post your inquiries over our Free Support Forums (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf).